# I could not understand intent.setAction(); not only this there are more stuff like this related to intents and activity's

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Can any one suggest some helpful links so that I can get free online tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not stating what docs you read. Have you read [Android dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html) ?

Comment: i have already gone through the android device guide but i need explanations along with example for each methods and/or API's...